# How to find the position of a value in an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

Think I have an array like 
A = { 1,2,3,4,5,6}
I need to get the position of 4 in this array.
I tried,
p = find(A==4)

Please help.

Comment: This is not an array, but a cell-array. Since your data is homogeneous, you are better off by using a numeric array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need a cell array (for example because the cells can contain vectors of different sizes):

```
A = {1, [1 2 3], 4, [1 2], [3 4]}; %// example cell array
sought = [1 2]; %// sought contents
index = find(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, sought), A));
```

Comment: I believe this is indeed the right way to do it, but must say that I am a bit dissapointed that basic functions like `find` or `ismember` do not appear to be readily available for cell arrays in Matlab.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I agree, this should be simpler to write

Comment: It is simpler to write `p=find([A{:}]==4)` will work.

Comment: That doesn't work in general. In my example, it would incorrectly detect the `4` in the last cell. And the indices wouldn't be correct

Comment: Agreed it doesn't work for your generalised example but for the question as originally posited then it works perfectly well.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, for that it works (+1 on your answer). But since you commented on my answer, I thought you were refering to my example

Comment: Thank you Very much.
I learnt a lot from this discussion.
I am quite new to matlab and still learning things.

Answer (score 3):

you created a cell-array instead of a normal vector.

Try:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
find(A==4)
```

Cell arrays are great to store variables with different types.You could, for example, create a cell array that contains strings as well as digits.

If you have only digits in your array you should defintely use normal arrays.
These are defined by **[ ]** instead of **{ }**

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined a cell array you need to convert it to a numeric array for find to work, fortunately this is simple to achieve with a couple of well placed brackets.

```
A = { 1,2,4,3,5,6};

find([A{:}]==4)

ans =

     3
```

So A{:} writes out the numeric values from your array and the [] contains the output for find to work.

p.s. I re-arranged the numbers in A to show that it was working as '4' is now in position 3 to provide a better test.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something here - I provide a very clean simple answer working with the original cell array as defined in the question and I get a down vote. I would appreciate the courtesy of a response as to why this answer is deemed 'not useful'.